# loadingStatus state for react-google-charts is set as loading permanantly

Tags: javascript

```
import { Chart } from "react-google-charts";

function SankeyGraph(props) {
  const data = [
    ["From", "To", "Weight"],
    ["A", "X", 5],
    ["A", "Y", 7],
    ["A", "Z", 6],
    ["B", "X", 2],
    ["B", "Y", 9],
    ["B", "Z", 4],
  ];

  const options = {};
  return (
    <Chart
      chartType="Sankey"
      width="40%"
      height="200px"
      data={data}
      options={options}
    />
  );
}

export default SankeyGraph;
```

```
{
  "loadingStatus": "loading",
  "google": null
}
```

This is the state of the component even after all the rendering is done, it stays in loading,  I tried the same code on code sandbox it worked fine.